# Why am I receiving a type error for Python?

Tags: python

"Write a program with total change amount as an integer input that outputs the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line. The coin types are dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies. Your program must define and call the following function. The function exact_change() should return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, and num_pennies."

The line "num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)" is what's giving me trouble but its a required line in the assignment.

The error says:
File "main.py", line 36, in 
num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```py
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    input_val = int(input())

num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)

    num_dollars = input_val // 100
    input_val %= 100
    num_quarters = input_val // 25
    input_val %= 25
    num_dimes = input_val // 10 
    input_val %= 10
    num_nickels = input_val // 5
    input_val %= 5
    num_pennies = input_val

    if num_dollars >1:
        print('%d dollars' % num_dollars)
    elif num_dollars ==1:
        print('%d dollar' % num_dollars)
    if num_quarters > 1:
        print('%d quarters' % num_quarters)
    elif num_quarters ==1:
        print('%d quarter' % num_quarters)
    if num_dimes >1:
        print('%d dimes' % num_dimes)
    elif num_dimes ==1:
        print('%d dime' % num_dimes)
    if num_nickels >1:
        print('%d nickels' % num_nickels)
    elif num_nickels ==1:
        print('%d nickel' % num_nickels)
    if num_pennies >1:
        print('%d pennies' % num_pennies)
    elif num_pennies ==1:
        print('%d penny' % num_pennies)
if input_val <= 0:
    print('no change')
```

The error says:

File "main.py", line 36, in 
num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: You need to show your `exact_change` function. It is clearly returning None instead of whatever is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing Zybooks for Python coding as well. This is how the code should look in order to pass all the programs' tests.

```
#define exact change function
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars = user_total // 100 #convert to dollars
    user_total %= 100 #get remainder after conversion
    num_quarters = user_total // 25 #convert to quarters
    user_total %= 25 #get remainder after conversion
    num_dimes = user_total // 10 #convert to dimes
    user_total %= 10 #get remainder after conversion
    num_nickels = user_total // 5 #convert to nickels
    user_total %= 5 #get remainder after conversion
    num_pennies = user_total
    return(num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_val = int(input()) #prompt user to input an integer
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val) #recall exact_change function
    
    #define output statements to output number of exact_change variables: 
    #num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies  
    if input_val <=0: #if amount is zero
        print('no change') #print output
        
    else:
        if num_dollars > 1: #if number of dollars is greater than one
            print('%d dollars' % num_dollars) #print number of dollars
        elif num_dollars == 1: # if number of dollars equal 1
            print('%d dollar' % num_dollars) #print dollar in singular
        
        if num_quarters > 1: #if number of quarters is greater than one
            print('%d quarters' % num_quarters) #print number of quarters
        elif num_quarters ==1: # if number of quarters equal 1
            print('%d quarter' % num_quarters) #print quarter in singular
        
        if num_dimes > 1: #if number of dimes is greater than one
            print('%d dimes' % num_dimes) #print number of dimes
        elif num_dimes == 1: # if number of dimes equal 1
            print('%d dime' % num_dimes) #print dime in singular
            
        if num_nickels > 1: #if number of nickels is greater than one
            print('%d nickels' % num_nickels) #print number of nickels
        elif num_nickels == 1: # if number of nickels equal 1
            print('%d nickel' % num_nickels) #print nickel in singular
        
        if num_pennies >1: #if number pennies is greater than one
            print('%d pennies' % num_pennies) #print number of pennies
        elif num_pennies ==1: # if number of pennies equal 1
            print('%d penny' % num_pennies) #print penny in singular
```

Comment: Simply giving someone the solution to an academic assignment is not helping them. StackOverflow is not here to enable cheating but to help someone understand concepts to become a better programmer.

Answer (score 1):

#I was pulling my hair out for a while with this. The above comments are right, but below is a little better due to IF a negative number is entered it stops the script.

```
import sys

amount_input = int(input())

dollars = amount_input // 100
quarters = amount_input % 100 // 25
dimes = amount_input % 100 % 25 // 10
nickels = amount_input % 100 % 25 % 10 // 5
pennies = amount_input % 100 % 25 % 10 % 5 // 1

if amount_input <= 0:
    print("No change")
    sys.exit()

if dollars > 1:
    print(str(dollars) + " Dollars")
elif dollars == 1:
    print(str(dollars) + " Dollar")
else:
    pass
if quarters > 1:
    print(str(quarters) + " Quarters")
elif quarters == 1:
    print(str(quarters) + " Quarter")
else:
    pass
if dimes > 1:
    print(str(dimes) + " Dimes")
elif dimes == 1:
    print(str(dimes) + " Dime")
else:
    pass
if nickels > 1:
    print(str(nickels) + " Nickels")
elif nickels == 1:
    print(str(nickels) + " Nickel")
else:
    pass
if pennies > 1:
    print(str(pennies) + " Pennies")
elif pennies == 1:
    print(str(pennies) + " Penny")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
def main(): 
  input_val = int(input('Enter change: '))
  if input_val <= 0:
    print('Some error message')
  else:
    #the rest of the code you provided 
    num_dollars = input_val // 100
    input_val %= 100
    num_quarters = input_val // 25
    input_val %= 25
    num_dimes = input_val // 10 
    input_val %= 10
    num_nickels = input_val // 5
    input_val %= 5
    num_pennies = input_val

    if num_dollars >1:
        print('%d dollars' % num_dollars)
    elif num_dollars ==1:
        print('%d dollar' % num_dollars)
    if num_quarters > 1:
        print('%d quarters' % num_quarters)
    elif num_quarters ==1:
        print('%d quarter' % num_quarters)
    if num_dimes >1:
        print('%d dimes' % num_dimes)
    elif num_dimes ==1:
        print('%d dime' % num_dimes)
    if num_nickels >1:
        print('%d nickels' % num_nickels)
    elif num_nickels ==1:
        print('%d nickel' % num_nickels)
    if num_pennies >1:
        print('%d pennies' % num_pennies)
    elif num_pennies ==1:
        print('%d penny' % num_pennies)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = int(input())
if user_input > 0:    
    dollar = user_input // 100
    user_input %= 100
    quarter = user_input // 25
    user_input %=25
    dime = user_input //10
    user_input %= 10
    nickel = user_input // 5
    user_input %= 5
    penny = user_input
    
    if dollar == 1:
        print(dollar, "Dollar")
    elif dollar > 1: 
        print(dollar, "Dollars")
    if quarter == 1:
        print(quarter, "Quarter")
    elif quarter > 1: 
        print(quarter, "Quarters")
    if dime == 1:
        print(dime, "Dime")
    elif dime > 1: 
        print(dime, "Dimes")    
    if nickel == 1:
        print(nickel, "Nickel")
    elif nickel > 1: 
        print(nickel, "Nickels")    
    if penny == 1:
        print(penny, "Penny")
    elif penny > 1: 
        print(penny, "Pennies")
else:
    print("No change")
```

Comment: Hello again. It would be helpful if you posted some kind of explanation here as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginning programmer and as far as my class has got in zybooks, i think this is the best route
it passes the test

```
total_change=int(input())

num_dollars=total_change//100
num_quarters=(total_change-num_dollars*100)//25
num_dimes=(total_change-num_dollars*100-num_quarters*25)//10
num_nickels=(total_change-num_dollars*100-num_quarters*25-num_dimes*10)//5
num_pennys=(total_change-num_dollars*100-num_quarters*25-num_dimes*10-num_nickels*5)//1

#no change 
if total_change<=0:
   print('No change')
#dollars
if 0<num_dollars<=1:
   print(num_dollars,'Dollar')
if num_dollars>1:
   print(num_dollars,'Dollars')
#quarters  
if 0<num_quarters<=1:
   print(num_quarters,'Quarter')
if num_quarters>1:
   print(num_quarters,'Quarters')
#dimes   
if 0<num_dimes<=1:
   print(num_dimes,'Dime')
if num_dimes>1:
   print(num_dimes,'Dimes')
#nickels   
if 0<num_nickels<=1:
   print(num_nickels,'Nickel')
if num_nickels>1:
   print(num_nickels,'Nickels')
#pennys
if 0<num_pennys<=1:
   print(num_pennys,'Penny')
if num_pennys>1:
   print(num_pennys,'Pennys')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using a while loop. . .

```
def exact_change(user_total):
        dollar,quarter,dime,nickel,penny = 100,25,10,5,1
        dollar_out, quarter_out, dime_out,nickel_out, penny_out = 0,0,0,0,0

while user_total > 0:
    if user_total >= dollar:
        dollar_out = dollar_out + 1
        user_total = user_total - dollar

    elif user_total >= quarter:
        quarter_out = quarter_out + 1
        user_total = user_total - quarter

    elif user_total >= dime:
        dime_out = dime_out + 1
        user_total = user_total - dime

    elif user_total >= nickel:
        nickel_out = nickel_out + 1
        user_total = user_total - nickel

    else:
        penny_out = user_total
        user_total = 0

return {"dollars" if (dollar_out > 1) else "dollar": dollar_out,
       "quarters" if (quarter_out > 1) else "quarter": quarter_out,
       "dimes" if (dime_out > 1) else "dime": dime_out,
       "nickels" if (nickel_out > 1) else "nickel": nickel_out,
       "pennies" if (penny_out > 1) else "penny": penny_out,}


if __name__=="__main__":
    input_val = int(input())

if input_val == 0:
    print("no change")

else:
    res = exact_change(input_val)
    for key, value in res.items():
        if value > 0:
            print(value, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question took me a long time to solve.
After looking at everybody else's code here, mine looks the shortest.
I hope I was able to help someone out there.

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars = int(user_total // 100)
    num_quarters = int((user_total - (num_dollars * 100)) // 25)
    num_dimes = int(((user_total - (num_dollars * 100)) - (num_quarters * 25)) // 10) 
    num_nickels = int(((user_total - (num_dollars * 100)) - (num_quarters * 25) - (num_dimes * 10)) // 5) 
    num_pennies = int(((user_total - (num_dollars * 100)) - (num_quarters * 25) - (num_dimes * 10) -(num_nickels * 5))) 
    return num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    input_val = int(input())    
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)
    
     # Type your code here.
    total = {'dollars':num_dollars, 'quarters': num_quarters, 'dimes': num_dimes, 'nickels': num_nickels, 'pennies': num_pennies}
    change = total
    
    if input_val == 0:
        print('no change')

    for x in change:
        if change[x] == 0:
            pass
        if change[x] == 1:
            print('{} {}'.format(change[x], x.replace('s','').replace('pennie', 'penny')))
        if change[x] > 1:
            print('{} {}'.format(change[x], x))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

```
change = int(input()) 
Dollar = [100, "dollar", "dollars"] 
Quarter = [25, "quarter", "quarters"] 
Dime = [10, "dime", "dimes"] 
Nickel = [5, "nickel", "nickels"] 
Penny = [1, "penny", "pennies"] 

if change == 0:
    print("no change")
else:
    def change_count(user_total,currency_type):
        num_num = int(user_total/currency_type[0])
        if num_num == 1:
            print(num_num, currency_type[1])
        elif num_num > 1:
            print(num_num, currency_type[2])
        global change
        change = change - (num_num * currency_type[0])
        return change
    
    
    change_count(change, Dollar)
    change_count(change, Quarter)
    change_count(change, Dime)
    change_count(change, Nickel)
    change_count(change, Penny)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to unpack a function, yet the function does not exist(according to what you pasted on here). Here is your code WITHOUT functions. If you are trying to code this lab with functions, you can pass arguments and provide a parameter in the function to accomplish this

```
input_val = int(input())

if input_val <= 0:
    print('No change')
    
num_dollars = input_val // 100
input_val %= 100

num_quarters = input_val // 25
input_val %= 25

num_dimes = input_val // 10 
input_val %= 10

num_nickels = input_val // 5
input_val %= 5

num_pennies = input_val

if num_dollars >1:
    print('%d Dollars' % num_dollars)
elif num_dollars ==1:
    print('%d Dollar' % num_dollars)
    
if num_quarters > 1:
    print('%d Quarters' % num_quarters)
elif num_quarters ==1:
    print('%d Quarter' % num_quarters)
    
if num_dimes >1:
    print('%d Dimes' % num_dimes)
elif num_dimes ==1:
    print('%d Dime' % num_dimes)
    
if num_nickels >1:
    print('%d Nickels' % num_nickels)
elif num_nickels ==1:
    print('%d Nickel' % num_nickels)
    
if num_pennies >1:
    print('%d Pennies' % num_pennies)
elif num_pennies ==1:
    print('%d Penny' % num_pennies)
```

Though the code is a bit longer, I recommend using appropriate white space. It looks cleaner and you may find the mistake in your code easier. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code WITH functions. Typically you want to reduce the amount of code in main if possible. Functions will usually lead to more lines of code but the code will be more adaptable and readable in the long run :)

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    if user_total <= 0:  
        print('no change')
        
    num_dollars = user_total // 100 
    user_total -= (num_dollars * 100)
    if num_dollars == 1:  
        print(num_dollars , 'dollar')
    elif num_dollars > 1:
        print(num_dollars , 'dollars')
        
    num_quarters = user_total // 25
    user_total -= (num_quarters * 25) 
    if num_quarters == 1:
        print(num_quarters , 'quarter')
    elif num_quarters > 1:
        print(num_quarters , 'quarters')
        
    num_dimes = user_total // 10
    user_total = user_total - (num_dimes * 10)
    if num_dimes == 1:
        print(num_dimes , 'dime')
    elif num_dimes > 1:
        print(num_dimes , 'dimes')
        
    num_nickels = user_total // 5
    user_total = user_total - (num_nickels * 5)
    if num_nickels == 1:
        print(num_nickels , 'nickel')
    elif num_nickels > 1:
        print(num_nickels , 'nickels')
        
    num_pennies = user_total // 1
    if num_pennies == 1:
        print(num_pennies , 'penny')
    elif num_pennies > 1:
        print(num_pennies , 'pennies')
    
    return (num_dollars , num_quarters , num_dimes , num_nickels , num_pennies)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = exact_change(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_change = int(input())

if input_change == 0:
    print('No change')

dollars = input_change // 100
input_change -= dollars * 100
if dollars: print(dollars, 'Dollars' if dollars > 1 else 'Dollar')

quarters = input_change // 25
input_change -= quarters * 25
if quarters: print(quarters, 'Quarters' if quarters > 1 else 'Quarter')

dimes = input_change // 10
input_change -= dimes * 10
if dimes: print(dimes, 'Dimes' if dimes > 1 else 'Dime')

nickels = input_change // 5
input_change -= nickels * 5
if nickels: print(nickels, 'Nickels' if nickels > 1 else 'Nickel')

pennies = input_change
if pennies: print(pennies, 'Pennies' if pennies > 1 else 'Penny')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
change = int(input())
dollars = 0
quarters = 0
dimes = 0
nickels = 0
pennies = 0

if change == 0:
    print("No change")

while change >= 100:
    dollars = dollars + 1
    change = change - 100
    if dollars == 0:
        break

if dollars == 1:
    print(str(dollars) + ' Dollar')
elif dollars > 1:
    print(str(dollars) + ' Dollars')

while change >= 25:
    quarters = quarters + 1
    change = change - 25
    if quarters == 0:
        break

if quarters == 1:
    print(str(quarters) + ' Quarter')
elif quarters > 1:
    print(str(quarters) + ' Quarters')
    
while change >= 10:
    dimes = dimes + 1
    change = change - 10
    if dimes == 0:
        break

if dimes == 1:
    print(str(dimes) + ' Dime')
elif dimes > 1:
    print(str(dimes) + ' Dimes')
    
    

while change >= 5:
    nickels = nickels + 1
    change = change - 5
    if nickels == 0:
        break

if nickels > 1:
    print(str(nickels) + " Nickels")
elif nickels == 1:
    print(str(nickels) + " Nickel")
    
while change >= 1:
    pennies = pennies + 1
    change = change - 1
    if pennies == 0:
        break
    
if pennies == 1:
    print(str(pennies) + " Penny")
elif pennies > 1:
    print(str(pennies) + " Pennies")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars = user_total // 100
    user_total %= 100
    num_quarters = user_total // 25
    user_total %= 25
    num_dimes = user_total // 10
    user_total %= 10
    num_nickels = user_total // 5
    user_total %= 5
    num_pennies = user_total
    return(num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_val = int(input())
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = 
exact_change(input_val) #recall exact_change function
 
    if input_val <=0:
        print('No change')
    
    else:
        if num_dollars > 1:
            print('%d Dollars' % num_dollars)
        elif num_dollars == 1:
            print('%d Dollar' % num_dollars)
    
        if num_quarters > 1:
            print('%d Quarters' % num_quarters)
        elif num_quarters ==1: 
            print('%d Quarter' % num_quarters)
    
        if num_dimes > 1:
            print('%d Dimes' % num_dimes)
        elif num_dimes == 1:
            print('%d Dime' % num_dimes)
        
        if num_nickels > 1:
            print('%d Nickels' % num_nickels)
        elif num_nickels == 1:
            print('%d Nickel' % num_nickels)
    
        if num_pennies >1:
            print('%d Pennies' % num_pennies)
        elif num_pennies ==1:
            print('%d Penny' % num_pennies)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
change = int(input())

dollars = change // 100

quart = change % 100 // 25

dimes = change % 100 % 25 // 10

nick = change % 100 % 25 % 10 // 5

penn = change % 100 % 25 % 10 % 5 // 1

if change <= 0:

    print('no change')

else:
    if dollars >= 2:

        print ('{} Dollars'.format(dollars))

    if (dollars == 1):

        print('1 Dollar')
    
    
    if quart >= 2:
        print ('{} Quarters'.format(quart))
    if (quart == 1):
        print('1 Quart')
    
    if dimes > 2:
        print ('{} Dimes'.format(dimes))

    if (dimes == 1):
        print('1 Dime')
    
    if nick >= 2:
        print ('{} Nickles'.format(nick))
    if (nick == 1):
        print('1 Dime')
    
    if penn >= 2:
        print ('{} Pennies'.format(penn))
    if (penn == 1):
        print('1 Penny')
```